# Python IDLE is refusing to save and is the crashing when I try to save a file with a specific comment

Tags: python, python-2.7, crash, save, comments

I am running Python 2.7. I wrote some code in the IDLE. I found that it would not save the file. If I repeatedly try to save, IDLE just crashes completely. I found that if I removed the following comment, it would save:

```
#Add a fourth parameter, end, to the find function that specifies where to stop looking. Warning: This exercise is a bit tricky. The default value of end should be len(str), but that doesn't work. The default values are evaluated when the function is defined, not when it is called. When find is defined, str doesn't exist yet, so you can’t find its length.
```

Oddly, I found if I truncated the comment to the following, it **can** save:

```
#Add a fourth parameter, end, to the find function that specifies where to stop looking. Warning: This exercise is a bit tricky. The default value of end should be len(str), but that doesn
```

It does not seem to be the length of the comment, as this version, where the comment is split into two, also does not save:

```
#Add a fourth parameter, end, to the find function that specifies where to stop looking. Warning: This exercise is a bit tricky. The default value of end should be len(str), but that doesn
#’t work. The default values are evaluated when the function is defined, not when it is called. When find is defined, str doesn’t exist yet, so you can’t find its length.
```

I imagine there is some rule for comments that I don't know, so any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Trying using another text editor. see if problem persists.. I rec SublimeText3

Comment: Thanks. I may do so in the future, but my goal right now is to figure out what is going wrong here.

Comment: Feel free to chase ghost.  Are you on windows? You may want to reinstall python. that should install new version of IDLE... Havent used IDLE in many years, There just better editors out there..

Comment: If you save your code in notepad with a .py extension, you should then be able to open it in IDLE and continue editing and saving without any further issue.

Answer (score 3):

You have to go in Options -> Configure IDLE -> General and set Default Source Encoding as UTF-8 option.

Comment: that option doesn't seem to exist

Answer (score 0):

Try again after Restarting your computer.

If not-resolved Try visiting

> > https://bugs.python.org/issue14996

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I tried restarting. No dice. I looked through the ticket. Unfortunately, the problem they have seems to be about the directory being saved into, rather than the content of the file. None of the fixes (which did not work for that user) seemed to work here either.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem as you do. I found that apparently IDLE overloads or some sort after you type in more than 10 characters and save. I try to save Ctrl+S every time i write a word, that seems to be the only way it is able to save. If you find any other way to fix the problem be sure to notify!